# EZ Generator Switch with Generac GB1000 and gas furnace

Tags: electrical, battery, transfer-switch, power-backup

Can I use an [EZ Generator Switch](https://ezgeneratorswitch.com) as a transfer switch with a [Generac GB1000 battery](https://www.generac.com/specialpages/portable-power-station) and a gas furnace (Bryant 340aav). If so, should it be setup as bonded neutral or floating neutral (I'm guessing it's supposed to be floating neutral). If not, is there a transfer switch that would work? (maybe Reliance Controls?)

Comment: FYI you're not going to get much run time with a 1000Wh battery. Depending on the specific furnace model you have, the blower fan alone takes 500-1000W. So maybe one or two hours of total runtime, if you're lucky (likely less, because the fan isn't the only load). https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/340AAVUser2.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the EZ Generator Switch is perfectly usable *and uniquely suited* for furnaces - pretty much the "killer app" for that particular product.

Your furnace will already have a steel Handy-Box containing a switch and/or fuse.  You simply replace the Handy-Box with - well, follow the instructions.

The only thing I don't like is the need to leave door cracked open for the extension cord, since carbon monox.... ***battery, duh***, nevermind!

Honestly, I'm not sure the battery is going to work for you.  These "solar generators" or "portable power stations" or whatever they call them these days, are **biblically overpriced** for what you get.  You can tell they're scammy because you have to dig deep in the specs for **The Single Most Important Parameter** for these units that should be right up front. But they *really, really* do not want you to be a competent shopper, because if you were, you probably wouldn't buy one. At least not theirs lol.

As it happens the "1000" unit is 1000 Watt-Hours, and the "2000" unit is 2000 watt-hours.  (Well OK it's in the model number, but you can't take that for granted, ever!)  1000 watt-hours is about the storage you can expect from a $150 car battery (better: deep cycle marine starting battery) from CostCo.  And so you can rely on data from people who have tried running their furnace off a car battery, [like this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkyPBAz0mLw).

I don't agree with the hatchet job the guy did wiring up the furnace - it doesn't switch neutral like it needs to, and I don't see a fuse.

That video's report of 6 hours feels about right to me.  Furnaces take a lot of power.  Once you install the switch, switch it to generator and feed your furnace through an extension cord via a wall outlet and a Kill-A-Watt.  It will read out the watts it is using.

Mind you, this only works because it's a gas furnace, and it's only using electricity to push the fluid around (e.g. air, or water in a hydronic system). A furnace that uses electricity as the literal heat source simply will not work on battery.

The cost of lithium batteries has dropped like a stone in the last 10 years, to 15 cents a watt-hour. The "power stations" haven't dropped a nickel and are still at $1 a watt-hour. I do not like them, I think they are insanely oversold to 1%ers and dumb people, and 99% of buyers think they will do more than they will do, because they don't understand amps and watts and watt-hours.

Comment: "A furnace that uses electricity as the literal heat source simply will not work on battery" - is that a challenge? how many LiFePO4s do you think I'd be able to pile up before the floor would cave in?

Comment: @user253751 or until the batteries themselves combust and become the heat source...

Comment: Spot on about value for money.   $1000 to keep your furnace running a few hours if you have a gas water or steam system, or maybe an hour if you have forced air.   For that period of time I have a much better system, it's called a "jacket".

Comment: Yeah, I'm a huge fan of battery/electric, but forced air furnaces are just too power-hungry. We have a Williams/Montery 50k BTU wall furnace that requires no electricity, and I don't understand why it isn't a standard feature in every snow belt home with gas.  Use it as emergency heat, with a modern heat pump or a condensing gas furnace as primary. Needing electricity for heat - what a dumb idea. Forced-air only exists because it enables 1959-era A/C systems.  Today, we have mini-splits.

Comment: @user253751 at that point you'd just buy a wrecked Nissan Leaf at an auction, and take the battery and battery charger out of it. Now for a couple grand you have a 16-40 kWH battery pack and fast charger.  Now you need an inverter and some bits, but you can see why I think those $1000 Jackery's are good money after bad. . You need some more bits, but you can see why I consider Jackerys to be "good money thrown after bad".

Comment: @user253751 actually now that I think about it, use a Bolt or Tesla pack. They have water cooling, so you can take the battery heat and use it to heat the house  LOL.